# Django Model " has more than one ForeignKey to "

Tags: python, django

there are two Models, `User` And `Friends`. I want to make two users make friends,but it did work.

the console just said,

> django.core.management.base.CommandError: System check identified some issues:
>
> ERRORS:
>   : (admin.E202) 'api4android.Friends' has more than one ForeignKey to 'api4android.User'.

here is the code

```
class Friends(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, related_name='user')
    friend = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, related_name='friend')
    note_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

def __str__(self):  
    return self.note_name
```

hope my poor english makes you understand what i mean.

Answer (score 36):

In your **admin.py** you have to specify **fk_name** to each relation.
Example:

```
class FriendshipInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Friendship
    fk_name = "user"
```

More info:
[Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.fk_name)

Comment: why is it `to_person` how did this become the right fk_name = ? ?

Comment: The `fk_name` should be whatever the field name is that you want the inline admin to list results for, so in this person’s example, if they want FriendshipInline to appear in the User admin, then they’d want `fk_name = "user"`.

([updated Django Docs link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.fk_name))

Comment: -1 You should either explain why you set fk_name to `to_person` or just use an example based off of the OP's code (which, like @MrColes said, would have resulted in fk_name being `user`).

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this

```
class Friends(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    friend = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, related_name='friend')
    note_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

def __str__(self):  
    return self.note_name
```

Comment: It didnt work! <class 'api4android.admin.FriendsInline'>: (admin.E202) 'api4android.Friends' has more than one ForeignKey to 'api4android.User'.

Comment: which version of django are you using?